# How to Set ApplicationBar Foreground using PhoneThemeManager

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I've had some problems getting this to work, with no luck on researching. I love Jeff Wilcox's PhoneThemeManager that is available via NuGet http://www.nuget.org/packages/PhoneThemeManager but I have a serious issue overriding the application bar settings to generate my own custom foreground/background. I'd like to use #6D4689 as the foreground with the default Light theme. My question is, simply setting the ApplicationBar foreground color in my MainPage does not work. How can I fix this?

App.xaml

```
ThemeManager.ToLightTheme();
```

EDIT

link to PhoneThemeManager on GitHub which shows source

https://github.com/jeffwilcox/wp-thememanager

Comment: can you provide the code where you are setting the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `ThemeManagerOverrideOptions` property. Setting it to `None` should help:

```
ThemeManager.OverrideOptions = ThemeManagerOverrideOptions.None;
ThemeManager.ToLightTheme();
```